# python typing: overload vs TypeVar

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I asked myself if there is a best practice concerning the use of `TypeVar` and `overload` in python for functions that return the same type as the input. Consider these examples.

Example 1. using `TypeVar`:

```
from typing import TypeVar

StrOrInt = TypeVar("StrOrInt", str, int)

def return_same_type_typevar(x: StrOrInt) -> StrOrInt:
    if isinstance(x, str):
        # process str
        return x
    else:
        # process int
       return x
```

Example 2, using `overload`:

```
from typing import overload

@overload
def return_same_type_overload(x: str) -> str:
    ...

@overload
def return_same_type_overload(x: int) -> int:
    ...

def return_same_type_overload(x):
    if isinstance(x, str):
        # process str
        return x
    else:
        # process int
       return x
```

Are the two examples actually achieving the same? Is this use of `overload` discuraged here and should `overload` only be used when the return type is different from the input type? Or is it fine but overly verbose?

Of course this is a trivial example. The code I am looking at would probably more take a pandas `Series` or `DataFrame` as input and not `str` and `int`.

---

edit: updated example to show that there are different code paths for `int` and `str`

Comment: Does the function actually do something significantly different for int vs str?

Comment: Yes, that's of course only a trivial example, assume there are different code pats for `int` and `str`. I'll try to update the examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no general "best practice", but when applicable the `TypeVar` is superior in any case.

- Using a `TypeVar` is shorter. Every additional type is one additional argument, versus 2-3 lines for an overload.
- Using a `TypeVar` is clearer. It immediately expresses that all variants do work fundamentally the same, whereas `overload` could have additional parameters.
- Using a `TypeVar` is more informative. The runtime function keeps its annotation for introspection, whereas the `overload` annotation is discarded.

Prefer to restrict `overload` to cases that significantly differ in their signature, i.e. have additional or restricted parameters in specific variants.